# How to force use of reflected dunders `__r...__`?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to force `some_numpy_array + CustomObject` to call `CustomObject.__radd__` instead of numpy's `__add__`, which doesn't work in my case. How can I do that?

Example:

```
import numpy as np

class CustomObject:    # as co

    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CustomObject):
            return self.arr + other.arr
        return self.arr + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

npa = np.array([1, 10.])
coa = CustomObject(npa)
print(npa + npa)   # [ 2. 20.] # np.__add__
print(coa + coa)   # [ 2. 20.] # co.__add__
print(coa + npa)   # [ 2. 20.] # co.__add__
print(npa + coa)   # [array([ 2., 11.]) array([11., 20.])] # np.__add__ where I want co.__radd__
```

Comment: You can't, except by calling it directly. If `left.__add__(right)` doesn't return `NotImplemented`, `right.__radd__(left)` won't be tried: [_" These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types."_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

Comment: Technically, you could monkey-patch the array object to replace its `__add__` method with one that does return `NotImplemented` when called with an `other` of your custom class. That would be a hack though, the saner way would be to simply implement and call an appropriate method for the addition instead of using the `+` operator.

Comment: A `ndarray` has a `__array_priority__` value of 0.0.  `np.matrix` sets this to 10.0, `masked_array` to 15.

Comment: Setting `__array_priority__` to a high value worked !